# Записать адрес памяти, используя cin

Tags: c++, cin

Есть переменная `int *Pointer_A;` не проинициализированная
Как записать в неё собственноручно нужный адрес?
Пробовал `std::cin>>*Pointer_A;` но это не работает

Comment: Просто `cin >> Pointer_A;` — но вы уверены в том, что вы хотите сделать?...

Comment: C++ отсутствует оператор, соответствующий этим операндам            типы операндов: std::istream >> int * (Выводит эту ошибку)

Comment: Считывайте беззнаковое целое размером с указатель (`::std::uintptr_t`), потом копируете его в указатель.

Comment: Подскажите как это сделать кодом? Я не совсем понял что написано.

Comment: `uintptr_t a; cin >> a; Pointer_A = (__typeof__(Pointer_A))a;`